# Why aren't min-width and max-width working as I expect?

Tags: css

I'm trying to adjust a CSS page layout using min-width and max-width. To simplify the problem, I made this test page. I'm trying it out in the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome with the same results.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Testing min-width and max-width</title>
    <style type="text/css">
       div{float: left; max-width: 400px; min-width: 200px;}
       div.a{background: orange;}
       div.b{background: gray;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="a">
      (Giant block of filler text here)
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      (Giant block of filler text here)
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's what I **expect** to happen:

- With the browser maximized, the divs sit side by side, each 400px wide: their maximum width
- Shrink the browser window, and they both shrink to 200px: their minimum width
- Further shrinking the browser has no effect on them

Here's what **actually happens**, starting at step 2:

- Shrink the browser window, and as soon as they can't sit side-by-side at their max width, the second div drops below the first
- Further shrinking the browser makes them get narrower and narrower, as small as I can make the window

So here's are my questions:

- What does `max-width` mean if the element will sooner hop down in the layout than go lower than its maximum width?
- What does `min-width` mean if the element will happily get narrower than that if the browser window keeps shrinking?
- Is there any way to achieve what I want: have these elements sit side-by-side, happily shrinking until they reach 200px each, and **only then** adjust the layout so that the second one drops down?

And of course...

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

I think (and this is just from my own personal experience), that max-width applies to the content inside the div. So if there was only 1 word inside the div, it would be 200px wide but if there were 300 words in a div, the width would be 400px wide.

I think there is a way to do what you want to do. This article might relate to it:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-tutorials/quick-tip-different-layouts-for-different-widths/

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The reason they're "dropping down" is due to the changing size of their parent element (in this case `body`). Put a wrapper `div` around them with a width of 400 pixels or more and you can keep them sitting side-by-side.

Comment: Wrapped a div around them both and gave it one rule: `width: 900px;`. Now they don't ever sit side by side. Tried adding a left float in case it was collapsing. No change.

Answer (score 1):

To answer at least a bit:

`min-width` really is about when the browser should show a horizontal scroll bar for the page.

Whilst experimenting floats only really work well when they have a `width` set, so I'd use a parent `div` with a min and max width set and add `width: 50%` to the child divs. This solves all your problems apart from the divs changing layout. For this I'd probably refer to javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Testing min-width and max-width</title>
    <style type="text/css">
       div.cont {max-width: 700px; min-width: 400px;}
       div.a, div.b {float: left; width: 50%; }
       div.a{background: orange;}
       div.b{background: gray;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="cont">
    <div class="a">
      Morbi malesuada nulla nec purus convallis consequat... 
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      Vivamus id mollis quam. Morbi ac commodo nulla... 
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```